# How do i post wav file data with curl c++ source , how do i use --data-binary with c++?

Tags: c++, file, curl, libcurl, wav

I'd like to send wav file with curl. i can send wav file using `--data-binary` with terminal command.
But i failed to send wav file with `c++ source`.

I used Linux,ubuntu 18.04

What is the curl_easy_setopt for `--data-binary`??

My code is below here..

I'd like to send wav file with curl. i can send wav file using `--data-binary` with terminal command.
But i failed to send wav file with `c++ source`.

I used Linux,ubuntu 18.04

What is the curl_easy_setopt for `--data-binary`??

My code is below here..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{

    std::string contents;
    std::ifstream in("test2.wav", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (in)
    {
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
    }


    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
    static const char buf[] =  "Expect:";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    // set up the header
    curl_formadd(&formpost,
        &lastptr,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "cache-control:",
        CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "no-cache",
        CURLFORM_END);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
        &lastptr,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "content-type:",
        CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "audio/wav",
        CURLFORM_END);


    curl = curl_easy_init();

    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
    if (curl) {

        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: audio/wav");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, contents.data());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:9080");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));


        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        curl_formfree(formpost);

        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt, and explain how it works or don't work.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Answer (score 1):

`--data-binary` is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, but you're doing a couple of mistakes here:

- your code is trying to mix a "multipart/form-data" POST request and a normal POST request together, the result is likely some garbled mess that the server can't parse. make up your mind, use either a normal POST request, *OR* use a multipart/form-data request, but don't mix the 2 in the same request (that's what your code is doing), to fix it just remove all the `formpost` code, you don't want a multipart request here.
- you are trying to send a binary file which may (and almost certainly does) include NULL-bytes, by default curl will use strlen() to check the size of the data to send, which stops at the first null byte, so your transfer will be incomplete. use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE` to tell curl how many bytes your binary file is.
- you are returning a success code even if the curl handle couln't be created. (i thought i saw 3 issues when reading through it at first but now i only see 2, hmm)